# Why $[|X|=\infty]\subset\{\cup^\infty_{k=1}[|X_k|=\infty]\}\cup\{\cap^\infty_{n=1}[X_n<\infty,|X_n-X]\geq1]\}$ implies $X$ is a.e. finite?

Tags: measure-theory

A given sequence of a.e. finite and measurable functions $X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots$ is said to *converge in measure* to the measurable function $X$ taking values in $\bar{R}$ (to be denoted by $X_{n} \rightarrow_{\mu} X$ as $\left.n \rightarrow \infty\right)$ if
$\mu\left(\left[\left|X_{n}-X\right| \geq \varepsilon\right]\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty, \quad$ for all $\varepsilon>0$
[This implies that $X$ must be finite a.e., as

**$$[|X|=\infty]\subset\{\cup^\infty_{k=1}[|X_k|=\infty]\}\cup\{\cap^\infty_{n=1}[X_n<\infty,|X_n-X]\geq1]\}$$**

I don't quite get the last part of the definition of the convergence in measure. Could someone please kindly explains why to express the set of all X taking value of infinity as a union of two disjoint sets implies $X$ must be finite a.e. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the measure of both sides yields
$$\mu\{|X|=\infty\} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu\{|X_k|=\infty\} + \mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n < \infty, |X_n-X| \ge 1\}\right)$$

The terms in the first sum are zero since $X_k$ is finite a.e.

The second term satisfies the following for any choice of $N$
$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n < \infty, |X_n-X| \ge 1\}\right)
\le \mu\{|X_N - X| \ge 1\}.$$
Taking $N \to \infty$ shows this term is also zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. Can I ask why the measure of the sets goes to 0 means that the value cannot be taken at infinity? Or it's like some sort of "weak" condition?

Comment: @JoZ My answer actually implies $\mu\{|X|=\infty\} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it now!